# Checking multiple same tabs in javascript , browser issue

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

I am trying to make a script, which will work on all of the browser, I got it work on firefox an ie. on chrome, the alert message is displayed for the first tab opened , but I am not redirected . It should be displayed for the first time. Any idea ? a

I want to check if I have the same tab opened multiple times. if yes, then do a redirect to another page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Opera 8.0+
    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Firefox 1.0+
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
    var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));
    // Internet Explorer 6-11
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    // Edge 20+
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    // Chrome 1+
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

    //only when an order is created
    var redirectFlag = false;
    if (+localStorage.tabCount > 0) {
        alert('There is already an order tab or window opened! You will be redirected to the customer grid!');
        redirectFlag = true;
    } else {
        localStorage.tabCount = 0;
    }
    localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount + 1;
    //works for firefox
    if (isFirefox) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (evt) {
            localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount - 1;
        });
    }
    //works for edge and ie
    if (isEdge || isIE) {
        window.addEventListener('onpagehide', function (evt) {
            localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount - 1;
        });
    }
    //doesn't work
    if (isChrome || isSafari || isOpera) {
        window.addEventListener('onunload', function (evt) {
            localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount - 1;
        });
    }
    //redirect user if there are 2 tabs/windows opened
    if (redirectFlag) {
        var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
        window.location.href = baseUrl + '/index.php/customer/';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Prefer feature detection over user agent sniffing.

Comment: [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) `= function(){}` should work on most Browsers.

Comment: @PHPglue Could you please add an answer with more explanation ? thank you

Comment: What's wrong with `onunload` and `localStorage`?

Comment: @PHPglue I access my TAB  on chrome, my localstorage become 1, I refresh the page , I got my alert message on chrome

Comment: That Browser detection code is pointless. If you do it right, you won't need that.